# Express: Render directory based on subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

Fairly straightforward problem here: I want to show different HTML based on the subdomain of the user. Here's what I have.

```
var app = express();
var userapp = connect();
var serveStatic = require("serve-static");
app.use(vhost("*.localhost", userapp));



  userapp.get("*", function (req, res, next) {
    
    // Get the subdomain
    var subdomain = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < req.get("host").length; i++) {
      if (req.get("host").charAt(i) === ".") {
        subdomain = req.get("host").substring(0, i);
        break;
      }
    }

    // Render the proper HTML file based on the subdomain
    userapp.use(serveStatic(path.join("./" + subdomain)));

    next();
  });

app.listen(4242);
```

Not sure where to go from here, nothing is rendered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to use `serveStatic` dynamically which is not possible. So you can't change your asset folder for each request.

Instead you can dynamically handle requests yourself with something like this:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  const fileName = 
    req.originalUrl === 'http://localhost:4242/index.html' ? 
    'index.html' : 'notFound.html'; 
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, fileName));
});
```

You need to manually figure out what is file path depending on URL and subdomain.

Comment: Yep, this was it. Didn't know serveStatic can't render dynamically, but looking at the name it seems kinda obvious now... Thanks a ton!